# How to use .png images instead of .gif images to show the image with animations in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app is a chatting app in which I need to show animated emoticons (just like (chuckle) in new skype versions) , Is there any way to implement some code in application to make use of .png files to make them show animated in chat window ?

Attaching example .png files here ,I searched the skype package contents and found that "Skype software is using the .png files for animations",any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try like this May be it helps you but not sure,

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:54]
for (int i = 0; i < 54; ++i) {
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image%d.png",i];
  [array addObject:image];
}
imageview.animationImages = array;
imageview.animationDuration = 1.00;
imageview.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[imageview startAnimating];
```

Comment: That can be done but the requirement is not to use number of images ,the image I attached here is a single image,they are not multiple images. Any guess how can we achieve this with a single image having multiple images embedded within it.